How to run Thunar with original text when using system with different locale?
I want to ask a question related to Thunar (or even Google something), but I'm not able to see original text.
I've tried to run:
LC_ALL=C thunar

but it just creates new instance of Thunar that already run. Is changing system settings and rebooting the only way to see English language in Thunar if you use different locale?
This is important when asking questions online, to show original text.
I actually wanted to ask a question here related to detection of file types in Thunar, they are In Polish (my locale). I want to see the English text for them.

Running LC_ALL=C thunar while Thunar is already running indeed just creates a new window,
ignoring the LC_ALL setting.
Thunar (and most other programs) only apply locale settings when starting the program,
not when opening a new window.
To display Thunar in English, you'll need to close all windows,
and open the first one with LC_ALL=C thunar. No need to reboot.

It didn't help LC_ALL=C makes no effect, I've also tried to kill thunar and run it again. Without success.
